# Map every item of one query output with another query output in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two independent queries that I want to merge in a way that each item of one output is mapped with every item of another output. Joining the table is not possible since we don't have any common field.

Output A

```
----
Date
----
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
```

Output B

```
----
Name
----
John Doe
Jane Smith
```

Desired Result

```
+-----------+-------------+
|   Date    |     Name    |
+-----------+-------------+
|2022-01-01 | John Doe    |
|2022-01-01 | Jane Smith  |
|2022-01-02 | John Doe    |
|2022-01-02 | Jane Smith  |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I can solve this by using full outer join with `on true` condition.

Example,

````
(SELECT DISTINCT(name) as name
FROM `dataset.names` A)
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT(date) as date
FROM `dataset.dates` A)
ON true```
````